# Can't upload files via PHP script on Synology Server

Tags: php, synology

Week ago I've transfer domain from outer hosting (all works properly) to to Synology Server on my desk. Since that time few things have stop work. I've repair some of them, but today I've noticed that I can't upload files.

I've changed owner to nobody (from root). I've checked /etc/php/php.ini but file_uploads = ON and  upload_max_filesize = 32M but still it doesn't work.

What else could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was simple: Filezilla shows me different chmod than ssh via putty. I've changed the and it works properly now